# how to make 2 virtualbox vms able to see each other via internal network but also be able to access the internet

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have 2 VMs (`A` and `B`) running locally (on host `H`) with VirtualBox and I would like to be able to:

1. ping `A` from `B` via an internal IP
2. ping `B` from `A` via an internal IP
3. ping 8.8.8.8 from `A`
4. ping 8.8.8.8 from `B`
5. access `A:22` from `H`
6. access `B:22` from `H`

I'm currently using the NAT network setting on `A` and `B`, so I'm able to satisfy all requirements above apart 1 and 2.

I've tried changing this to internal network which satisfied only 1 and 2.

I've also used bridged networking which solved all those points but the problem is that `A` and `B` where now "exposed" in the local LAN by using 192.168.0.X type of addresses, which doesn't satisfy the "internal IP" requirement of 1 and 2.

What network configuration should I do on those 2 VMs to achieve this?

Comment: What are the ip adresses of VM a, and b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding 2 adapters on each VM. One for `NAT` and one for `Host-only Adapter Network`.

On the `NAT` I configured port forwards from `2201` to `22` etc.
And when the VMs booted I had to configure their internal static IPs. They VMs are ubuntu so I had to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and add:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.0.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and on the other VM:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.0.0.102
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

After a `shutdown -r now` or a `ifup eth1`, the two VMs could ping each other via their internal IPs `10.0.0.101` and `10.0.0.102`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add (create) a NAT Network within Virtual Box
2. Connect each of the two VMs to that NAT network
3. Make sure that each VM has a unique MAC address
4. if you have statically assigned IP addresses, make sure each VM has a different IP address within the 10.0.2.0/24 ip range
5. if you want to ping VM B from VM A via its host name, add the host name of VM B and the matching IP into your hosts file on VM a (and vice versa)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The currently accepted answer necessarily over-complicates things.

Answer (score 0):

Change the network adapters to `NAT` (one network card per VM is enough). So they will be exposed only to the host and not the network the host is running on and you will be able to add a check mark to all 6 points you mentioned.

If some point later you will have to give access to those VMs from the network your host is attached to, you will be able to do so with forwarding rules.

Comment: By using `NAT` I can't satisfy #1 and #2, because both machines use `10.0.2.15` for themselves and `10.0.2.2` for the host. I don't know how `A` and `B` see each other that way.

Comment: Check your NAT settings, as both VMs should have different IPs. Check the MAC addresses of the VMs. They should be different. Have you setup the IPs as static or did you get it from the NAT DHCP?

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox and by using `NAT` in the VM's Settings > Network, the VM gets `10.0.2.15` and I don't know if this can be changed.

Comment: Per [VirtualBox Networking manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat) every VM should get a different IP. Check also here [Fine Tuning NAT](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changenat)

Comment: This answer is not correct. With NAT every VM gets the exact same IP address and cannot see each other, just the host. I think the confusion comes from the (very different, but confusingly named) "NAT Network" mode, in which a NATted virtual network is created and all VMs join in.